# Android PDF closes immediately after opening from assets folder - Intent

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to open a pdf file which is stored in the assets folder. The pdf file should be opened with an intent and as such should use a pdf reader which the user has already installed.

My current problem is that the pdf file opens for a second and then closes immediately.

This is my full code: https://github.com/Berki2021/ViewPDFRoom (I hope it is fine to share a github link)

And here the important snippet:

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val adapter = NoteAdapter()
        recycler_view.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
            recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
            this.adapter = adapter
        }

        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.application)
        ).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(note: Note) {
                // Open PDF by name
                readFromAssets(note.pdfName, baseContext)
            }
        })

        // Debugger => Not important for the question
        Stetho.initialize(
            Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(baseContext)
                .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(baseContext))
                .build()
        )
    }

    // The function I use to open a pdf
    fun readFromAssets(fileName: String, context: Context) {
        val file = File(baseContext.filesDir, fileName)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", file)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

I know that someone already asked the same question 3 years ago. But there was not a big response. I appreciate every help, thank you.

Comment: "I am trying to open a pdf file which is stored in the assets folder" -- you have no code for this. While you have a function named `readFromAssets()`, it has nothing to do with assets. You can use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method to get an `InputStream` on the asset, then copy that to some file. *Then* you can use `FileProvider` to try to open a PDF viewer on that file. See [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/PdfProvider) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) for a demonstration.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, I understand. So lets say, I don't want to store my pdf files in the assets folder, because I have to say, I don't really care where they are stored. Is there a possible way to open a pdf file with my example? Where do I have to store my pdf files in android studio (they should be on the device when the user installs my application).

Comment: "Where do I have to store my pdf files in android studio (they should be on the device when the user installs my application)" -- sorry, but Android does not do that. The solution that I outlined in my previous comment would be a typical way of handling this case. Alternatively, you can attempt to view the PDF straight from assets -- I have [an old library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) that handled that scenario.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay. I have another question: Lets say I want to update my pdf files which are stored in the assets folder. How do I make sure that the old pdf files are deleted when the user updates the app. Is this even possible?

Comment: "How do I make sure that the old pdf files are deleted when the user updates the app" -- you would have to delete (or replace) them yourself. The simple-but-inefficient solution is to replace them on every app launch. Alternatively, you could use naming conventions or something to be able to tell whether the currently-unpacked PDFs are up to date and only replace them on app launch if needed.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay, that makes sense, thank you. I will try to use your "old library" as it looks like it will serve my usage. But I get an "ERROR: Failed to resolve com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.5.3" when adding it to my gradle ._.

Comment: Did you add `maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"  }` to your `repositories`? See [the demo app `build.gradle` file](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/demo/build.gradle).

Comment: You could do that, or you could add it in the `app` module's `build.gradle` file, as [the demo app does](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/demo/build.gradle).

Comment: @CommonsWare oh, now it works! Thank you